How to train continuous probability distributions as output from a neural network?
I'm training time series models on numerical forecasting, and I'm seeing inherent difficulty in modeling the uncertainty of the values. Time series forecasting generally has a pattern of uncertainty that looks like the graphic below, with confidence intervals that widen the further out the prediction is.
My use case involves very noisy training data, and requires a more probabilistic output, incorporating knowledge of these confidence intervals, ideally with some representation of the predicted distribution of values as a probability density function output I can sample from.
It's been suggested that I bucket outputs into a histogram and assign each bucket to a different output, and then softmax to get my distribution, but the granularity of an inherently-discrete output isn't ideal.
I'd love some guidance on how to better structure the output of a model to produce a PDF I can sample from, and how to derive a loss for such a structure. As for the particular distributions involved, generally roughly a truncated skewed gaussian though the actual distribution only conforms loosely to that model. Ideally the output can represent a variety of different distributions though I'm not sure how I'd parameterize in a way that generalizes across distribution types.


it's not obvious how to model the whole $p(y|x)$ with neural network, however you can probably achieve a similar result using bayesian neural network
